# How to rank relatedness of two feature in dataset by their distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, data, feature-engineering

Let's say we are given a dataset and want to rank them by similarity of distributions. I don't want to use visualization. Is there any sufficient way that you can share with me?
I have an idea like, we can subtract some number of percentiles from features and find the mean of that.

```
def percentile(feature1, feature2, num_percentiles):
            percentiles1 = np.percentile(feature1, np.linspace(0, 100, num_percentiles))
            percentiles2 = np.percentile(feature2, np.linspace(0, 100, num_percentiles))

            difference = percentiles1 - percentiles2
            ranking = np.mean(np.abs(difference))

            return ranking
```

Can I use that?

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is the cosine similarity:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html

But, if your data is linear, you may prefer to use a correlation heatmap, based on the Pearson algorithm:
https://towardsdatascience.com/seaborn-heatmap-for-visualising-data-correlations-66cbef09c1fe

In both cases, you will want to check if the similarity is correct by taking some samples and verifying their consistency manually.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you proposed using percentiles and calculating the mean difference can be a simple way to rank datasets based on the similarity of their distributions. This method focuses on comparing the distribution characteristics of two features. However, it's important to note that this approach may not capture all aspects of the distributions and may overlook certain nuances.

There are more sophisticated statistical measures that can be used to assess the similarity of distributions. Here are a few alternatives you might consider:

1. Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test: The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is a statistical test that compares the cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) of two datasets. It quantifies the maximum difference between the CDFs, providing a measure of similarity between the distributions.
2. Jensen-Shannon Divergence: Jensen-Shannon Divergence is a symmetric measure of the similarity between two probability distributions. It calculates the average of the Kullback-Leibler divergences between the two distributions and their average distribution.
3. Earth Mover's Distance (EMD): The Earth Mover's Distance, also known as Wasserstein distance, measures the minimum amount of "work" required to transform one distribution into another. It considers the spatial relationship between data points and can capture both shape and location differences between distributions.
4. Bhattacharyya Distance: Bhattacharyya Distance is a statistical measure that quantifies the similarity between two probability distributions. It takes into account both the means and variances of the distributions, providing a metric that reflects their overlap.